# Reusing types for functions in React + TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a function defined in a parent component and it gets passed to a child component as a prop. Right now I do the type definitions for the function where it is declared and then I have to do the exact same type definition for the props on the child component.

This feels messy. I know that I could write a type def for the function and store it in some other file and then import that type into both the parent and child. If I do that then I either end up with a big file holding all of these type definitions or a bunch of small files holding fewer type definitions and thinking about both of those options feel a little overwhelming.

What’s the best approach here?

Parent

```
const foo = (str: string): void => {
    console.log(str);
}
// ...
return <Child foo={foo} />
```

Child

```
interface ChildProps {
    foo: (str: string) => void;
}
function Child(props: ChildProps) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can export `ChildProps`, then in parent use [indexed access operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#index-types) to get the type of the `foo` prop:

```
const foo: ChildProps['foo'] = str => {
    console.log(str);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIAtgBsAmAFKAewAcBnZAbwChlkZDCAuZAClLCmfalAHMBKZAF4AfMgBuhYDgDcVAL5UqCQiHZ0GzDNnxEyAbQDk9QoYC6w5N2FjqtFWsJYIAOiyFebDvznygA)

---

Or even without exporting child props type, you can use `ComponentProps` utility to get it:

```
import { ComponentProps } from 'react';

const foo: ComponentProps<typeof Child>['foo'] = str => {
    console.log(str);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYQuCA7AphmAFKCMAZzgF84AzQkOAciiwEMBjGOgbgCgvhcsolVlhQALYABsAJgSKkEXOFQgQAXHAAUxGFHXaofAOYBKOAF4AfHABuEYFO5kelAK4Y2wTGMlSNYQiTqyOLSsiSmCkqMMC5QGHAYLhISjjwsmNrKaihokNi4YcQAPDAAnmBYEJTe0hYA2nSUKnQAuuZw+uZWkXDpGMQQElgAdBIQhlo6xo5AA)